salesforce lwc Value provided is invalid for action parameter of type "LIST"
i have a aura enabled function that takes parameter of type list and i'm passing to it an array of that object but i'm receiving an error
Value provided is invalid for action parameter 'tasks' of type 'LIST'
@AuraEnabled
    public static GanttChartWrapper.Tasks addTasks(String projectId, list<GanttChartWrapper.Task> tasks){

 this.gantt.taskStore.on('add', ({ source, records, allRecords, parent, index, oldIndex, isChild, isExpand, isMove }) => { 
            if(!isExpand){ 
                let tasks2Insert = [];
                for(let record  of records){
                    if(!this.isSalesforceId(record.id)){
                        record.wbs = record.wbsCode;
                        record.projectId = this.recordId;
                        tasks2Insert.push(record);
                    }
                }
                if(tasks2Insert.length > 0){this.dbAddTasks(tasks2Insert, this.gantt.taskStore);}                
            }       
        });

dbAddTasks(records2Insert, allTasks){
        //this.inProgress = true;
        console.log('dbAddTasks');
        addTasks ( {projectId : this.recordId, tasks : records2Insert} )        
        .then(result => {            
            // this.inProgress = false;
            let savedTasks = result.rows;
            for(let task of allTasks){
                for(let savedTask of savedTasks){
                    if(savedTask.wbs == task.wbsCode){
                        task.id = savedTask.id;
                    }
                }    
            }
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('refreshView'));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // this.inProgress = false;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error Adding Taska',
                    message: getErrorMessage(error),
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
            //this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('closeView'));
        });
    }


The issue you're encountering is due to a data type mismatch. The error message indicates that the value provided for the tasks parameter is invalid because it's not of the expected type LIST. Specifically, you're passing an array of plain JavaScript objects instead of an array of Task objects.
To resolve this, you should use a wrapper class to facilitate the conversion between JavaScript objects and Apex objects. In your Apex code, you can deserialize the array of objects into a list of Task objects and process the data accordingly.
public class GanttChartWrapper {
// Inner class representing a Task
public class Task {
    @AuraEnabled public String id { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String wbs { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled public String projectId { get; set; }
    // Include other necessary fields here

    // Default constructor
    public Task() {}

    // Constructor to initialize a Task object from another Task object
    public Task(Task tasks) {
        this.id = tasks.Id;
        this.wbs = tasks.wbs;
        this.projectId = tasks.wbs;
        // Initialize other fields if needed

    }

    public Task getInstance() { 
        if (this.tasks!= null) return this.tasks;
        else {
            this.tasks= new Task();
            this.act.Id = this.Id;
          
            this.tasks.projectId = this.projectId;
            this.tasks.wbs = this.wbs;
            // if any custom fields
            this.tasks.number__c = this.number; // example for custom field
            return this.tasks;
        }
    }
}

// Method to add tasks
@AuraEnabled
public static void addTasks(String projectId, String tasks) {
    
 List<Task> ListTask = ((List<Task>)System.JSON.deserialize(tasks, List<Task>.class));
}


this.gantt.taskStore.on('add', ({ source, records, allRecords, parent, index, oldIndex, isChild, isExpand, isMove }) => { 
        if(!isExpand){ 
            let tasks2Insert = [];
            for(let record  of records){
                if(!this.isSalesforceId(record.id)){
                    record.wbs = record.wbsCode;
                    record.projectId = this.recordId;
                    tasks2Insert.push(record);
                }
            }
            if(tasks2Insert.length > 0){this.dbAddTasks(tasks2Insert, this.gantt.taskStore);}                
        }       
    });

dbAddTasks(records2Insert, allTasks){
    //this.inProgress = true;
    console.log('dbAddTasks');
    addTasks ( {projectId : this.recordId, tasks : JSON.Stringify(records2Insert)} ) //// Change to String value pass        
    .then(result => {            
        // this.inProgress = false;
        let savedTasks = result.rows;
        for(let task of allTasks){
            for(let savedTask of savedTasks){
                if(savedTask.wbs == task.wbsCode){
                    task.id = savedTask.id;
                }
            }    
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('refreshView'));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // this.inProgress = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error Adding Taska',
                message: getErrorMessage(error),
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
        //this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('closeView'));
    });
}

